# Why is Redactor cutting off Headings after Heading 2?

Tags: redactor

my client sees the attached screen in the editing window. it seems that Redactor is cutting off headings after Heading 2. They are using Chrome.
ideas?[image: Redactor truncating heading list]

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this on Craft 2.6.2971 using the latest Chrome with a normal Rich Text field or one inside of a Matrix field.  Are you running the latest Craft version? Do you have any plugins installed that might be interfering with the CSS/JS?

Comment: Is it just a scrollable list but without visible scroll bars? So the additional headings are there you just need to scroll the menu to see them?

Comment: @BradBell i am not able to reproduce it either. My client sees it — screenshot from them — and i am not certain of what to do next. i have asked them to update Chrome. Updating Craft will be my next step.

Comment: @SteveRowling Sort of. Not scrollable and no scrollbars. i have asked my client to update Chrome. Step 2 will be to check on updating Craft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client was using a Mac and the trackpad scrollbars are set to only show when over scrollable content. This is embarrassing, but the issue is resolved.